# Having trouble building a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, texlive

I am trying to build this tikz picture on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,line width=0.3mm,draw=black,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    \draw[->] (.45,0) -- (2.6,0) node[sloped,midway,above] {\footnotesize W\textsubscript{AB}};
    \draw[->] (.4,-.2) -- (2.7,-1.8) node[sloped,midway,above] {\footnotesize W\textsubscript{AC}};

    \draw[->] (3.45,0) -- (4.3,0) node[right=0cm]{Output\textsubscript{B}};
    \draw[->] (3.45,-2) -- (4.3,-2) node[right=0cm]{Output\textsubscript{C}};

    \node[neuron] at (0,0) {A};
    \node[neuron] at (3,0) {B};
    \node[neuron] at (3,-2) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, `pdflatex` is giving me this error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 ...idway,above] {\footnotesize W\textsubscript
                                                  {AB}};
```

What do I need to install?

Comment: Is your Tex Live distribution up-to-date? I can compile your code just fine. Try updating.

Comment: By the way, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. You should consider switching to `\tikzset`.

Comment: @Alenanno I am running texlive 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `subscript` defines `\textsubscript`.

This is not needed with the recent LaTeX version, where the definition for `\textsubscript` is already part of the LaTeX kernel.

For older LaTeX versions, `\textsubscript` is defined in package `fixltx2e`, from its documentation:

```
4  Fixes added for 2005/12/01
4.1 \textsubscript not defined in latex.ltx (pr/3492)
```

Comment: Loading package `fixltx2e` seems to have fixed it.

Comment: @mntruell Yes, I found an older [documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf) of the package (the link might be invalid in the future).